# Keep field visible when it is empty in Crystal Reports C#

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I have an application showing a Crystal Report, when the fields are not empty they be visible. Here's the screenshot:

[image: visible fields]

When some fields are empty, they will be hidden - see screenshot:

[image: hidden fields]

I use Visual Studio 2017, CR for VS_13_0_24 for Visual Studio 2017.

How to fix this problem? How to display fields even if they are empty?

Thanks

Comment: you want to hide the label when no value presented or what?

Comment: i want to show textbox fields specially string fields even when they have no value means empty, crystal report hide them when they have no value ,I want to keep them visible, i know i can use formula to check if they null and assign empty space like '     ', but this is take effort for 20 fields for example,is there an easy way?

Answer (score 0):

I end up using formula for each string field to check if empty or not,if someone has better way please post it, here an example:

```
if isnull({Shipment.SerialNumber}) or {Shipment.SerialNumber}='' then
'       '
else
{Shipment.SerialNumber}
```

Comment: yes this the right solution for that case